# Web scraping youtube page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to get the title of youtube videos given a link.

But i'm unable to access the element that hold the title. I'm using bs4 to parse the html.
I noticed im unable to access any element that is within 'ytd-app' tag in the youtube page.

```
import bs4
import requests

listed_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IfT8KXX_9c&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=31"
listed = requests.get(listed_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(listed.text, "html.parser")

a = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer"})
print(a)
```

So how can i get the video title ? Is there something i'm doing wrong or youtube intentionally created a tag like this to prevent web_scraping ?

Comment: You can use youtube_dl to parse youtube videos

Answer (score 1):

See class that you are using is render through Javascript and all the contents are dynamic so it is very difficult to find any data using `bs4`

So what you can do find data in soup by manually and find particular tag

Also you can try out with [pytube](https://pytube.io/en/latest/)

```
import bs4
import requests

listed_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IfT8KXX_9c&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=31"
listed = requests.get(listed_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(listed.text, "html.parser")

soup.find("title").get_text()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for my purpose !